# When trying to Install Shiny Server for R, the command in the setup instructions triggers a Bash syntax error, how do I fix it?

Tags: bash, r

So I'm trying to install shiny server for the R programming language on Ubuntu 12.04, using the information available at [this page on the program's github](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Ubuntu-step-by-step-install-instructions).

However, when I get to this step:

```bsh
# Install Shiny in system-wide library
sudo su - -c "R -e \\"install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\\""
```

I get the following:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two `"` characters are cancelling each other out at the beginning, I believe, because the quotes are incorrectly escaped.  I'm not certain why they have `\\"` (which is interpreted as an escaped `\` character with an unescaped `"` after that, and not an escaped `"` character) instead of `\"` which is the proper way to escape the quote, but that likely is the cause of this problem.

Try using this instead, it may work:

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

---

I have done some looking into this.  The instructions that were initially provided for this in the GitHub repository for the software have been marked as "Obsolete".

[This is the installation instructions that they now refer to](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/server/install-opensource).  If you are running into this issue, you should not be using the documentation on the GitHub repository, and should be using the new instructions instead.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you.  I'll check the box in 9 mins. when it let's me.

Comment: @JonathanRossCharlton glad to hear this worked!  [I opened up an issue with the project on Github](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/56) specifically identifying that the command incorrectly escapes the quote, triggering a syntax error, and I also pointed them to this question/answer so they can see why I noticed this.  This way they can fix this for others so that this doesn't happen in the future :)